# NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

After Updating the Xcode to "Version 12.4 (12D4e)" recently i am getting an error "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}" after running the simulator. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am running into the same error while trying to `registerForRemoteNotifications()`

Comment: Because you are on a simulator, you’ll see a Failed to register error.

Comment: when you run on a real device, you should receive a token in the console output.

Comment: Apple didn't add push notifications to the simulator, they added support for simulating push notifications. So this means that you cannot receive any push notifications, you can just simulate them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive push notifications in the simulator.

If you would like to disable this warning so that it doesn't clog up your terminal while developing, you can use `react-native-device-info` to detect if it is a simulator and then not register the push notifications:

```js
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

const requestPermission = async () => {

   if (DeviceInfo.isEmulator()) return;

   try {
      Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications();
   } 
   ...
}
```

Comment: ok agreed you can't receive real push notifications but you CAN simulate them by making a ".apns" file (JSON) format and drag-drop it onto your simulator window.